# Calculating shortest path with BFS in R

Tags: r, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I'm working with R to make a breadth-first search of a network.  Here is the code I have so far:

```
shortestPath <- function(v1,v2) {
  q <- rep(0, 3931)
  head <- 1
  head2 <- 0
  tail <- 1
  v1$distance <- 0
  q[tail] <- v1
  while(head <= tail) {
    v <- q[head]
    head <- head + 1
    if(v==v2) {
      return(v$distance)
      }
    vEdges <- get.neighborhood(net, v)
    m <- rep(0,3931)
    m[head2] <- v
    head2 <- head2 + 1
    for(n in vEdges) {
    if(!(n %in% m)) {
      n$distance <- v$distance + 1
      m[head2] <- n
      head2 <- head2 + 1
      tail <- tail + 1
      q[tail] <- n
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on with it.  It just gets stuck in the while loop infinitely.  The network I'm dealing with works and is fully connected.  I think there is just a minor problem with this that I'm not seeing, if anyone could put me in the right direction toward fixing this, that would be great.  I'm probably not as experienced as a typical R user.

Thanks.

Comment: Indenting your code makes it easier to see which code blocks form a unit, see my edit for how I would indent the code.

Comment: You might want to check out igraph: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/graph.bfs.html. There is almost never a need to reinvent the wheel in R when it comes to algorithmic approaches of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `while` loop just loops infinitely because the `head <= tail` is always TRUE, at the end of the graph `head == tail` I presume? I suspect `head < tail` is what you meant? In addition, I do not believe `return` breaks from the while loop, use `break` for that.

Comment: Thanks for both the edit and your answer.  If I do indeed set the while loop for `head < tail`, how do you recommend dealing with the head and tail values?  The way I have them set up, it requires it to be <= because they both start off at 1.